# STM32 CUBE IDE device not found on target

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

Hello i used to work on a project but now this messagew appears when i try to connect to st link

```
Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
        InitWhile                  : Enabled

Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.
```

Supply and microcontroller and st link cable seems okey

I checked connections and tried to urpgrade the firmware with cube programmer an it appears this message
Error no stm32 target found please perform a discovery using debug authentication

Answer (score 0):

Unplug stm32 from the PC and restart (not turn of and turn on but restart) the Computer. It helps in majority of cases.

Comment: It does not. In his case PC can communicate with ST-Link but ST-Link is unable to reach any STM32 chip connected to it.

Comment: in that case what the problem may be?

Comment: Did you check jumpers ? You can use st-link to program external processor (on your own hardware) . For example on nucleo boards there are jumperss you can see on photo here: https://www.visualmicro.com/page/STM32-Debugging.aspx

Comment: @Misaz is right it is not about st-link but about processor